# Android/Eclipse - How save working copies? Versioning?

Tags: eclipse, version

New to Eclipse, Android and Java, so this is sure to be a real newbie question...

I'm working on a simple project (say, display a button) and get it working in the emulator.  All is good.

Now I want to add a second button to my stunning app, but want to make sure if I horribly break the code, I can go back to my first working code and try again.  I don't really see a way to do this without creating a whole new project.  This seems kind of crazy, since I like to save the working versions pretty often so there isn't a lot of lost work/time.  Is there a better way?

Also, if this IS the way it is done, what is the best way to create a 'new' project which is simply a copy of the last working project (under a new project name)?

Thx.

Comment: I think that you are looking for something like git/svn.

Comment: Source control is probably what you are looking for. Have a look at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html